# BUILTIN\Administrators allowing access via linked server but not locally

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, security, linked-server, kerberos

We have two servers:

**LYNDB01 & LYNDB02**

On **LYNDB01** we have a database called **db_ExampleDatabase**

We have created a Linked Server on **LYNDB02** to **LYNDB01** using no mappings and the "Be made using the login's current security context" option for authentication:

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver @server = N'LYNDB01', @srvproduct=N'SQL Server'
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedsrvlogin @rmtsrvname=N'LYNDB01',@useself=N'True',@locallogin=NULL,@rmtuser=NULL,@rmtpassword=NULL
```

We have a windows user on **LYNDB02** for **DOMAIN\USER1** - this windows user **does not** have a login on **LYNDB01** at all but is a domain admin and thus is a member of **BUILTIN\Administrators** on both **LYNDB01** & **LYNDB02**

I have created a view in the **LYNDB01.db_ExampleDatabase** database to confirm what user is running the transaction:

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[vw_CurrentUser]
AS
    SELECT  SYSTEM_USER AS CurrentUser
```

For testing we gave **DOMAIN\USER1** RDP access to **LYNDB01** & **LYNDB02**.

If we RDP to **LYNDB01** as **DOMAIN\USER1** and open up SSMS with windows authentication - we get a logon error as **DOMAIN\USER1** does not have a login on **LYNDB01**, so that's fine.

If we RDP to **LYNDB02** as **DOMAIN\USER1** and open up SSMS with windows authentication it connects OK (Which is fine as **DOMAIN\USER1** has a login on **LYNDB02**). Here is our problem, we can access **LYNDB01.db_ExampleDatabase.dbo.vw_CurrentUser** via the Linked Server!

```
SELECT * FROM LYNDB01.db_ExampleDatabase.dbo.vw_CurrentUser
```

How is this possible when **LYNDB01** does not have a login on **LYNDB01** (Which is confirmed by the error we get when connecting locally!)

And yes, the remote query confirms that **DOMAIN\USER1** is the current user??

VERY confused?!

**Edit: Theroy 1**

**DOMAIN\USER1** is a domain admin and is therefore a local admin on both **LYNDB01** & **LYNDB02** - could this be causing it? if so, why would i get access denied on **LYNDB01** as **USER1** has no logon but work via a linked server?

OK, if i delete **BUILTIN\Administrators** logon from **LYNDB01** this problem goes away and the query from **LYNDB02** fails - why is **BUILTIN\Administrators** letting **USER1** authenticate remotely via a linked server but not locally & what can i do about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is expected. LUA strips administrators membership from your token. From [Getting Started with User Account Control on Windows Vista](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc507861.aspx):

> To help prevent malware silent installation and computer-wide infection, Microsoft developed the UAC feature for Windows Vista. Unlike previous versions of Windows, when an administrator logs on to a Windows Vista computer, the userâ€™s full administrator access token is split into two access tokens: a full administrator access token and a standard user access token. **During the logon process, authorization and access control components that identify an administrator are removed or disabled, resulting in a standard user access token.** The standard user access token is then used to launch the desktop, the Explorer.exe process. Because all applications inherit their access control data from the initial launch of the desktop, they all run as a standard user as well. Contrasting with this process, when a standard user logs on, only a standard user access token is created. This standard user access token is then used to launch the desktop.

Since your local desktop token has the administrator membership removed, it cannot log in locally to SQL Server if you expect to log in through `builtin\Administrators`. On remote access your token preserves the Administrator membership and you gain access.

The solution is to grant SQL Server login rights through an explicit domain group account and add all users that require access to your SQL instance to this domain group. Do not rely on Administrators membership, is a bad practice.

Comment: Argh, so simple now i think about it - cheers. The reason this came up is that we realised our domain admins pretty much had full access to SQL via linked servers - is this something we should just accept and trust our Domain Admins? Everything ive read about removing the BUILTIN\Administrators group says that this can often be more trouble than it's worth?

Comment: Domain admins have access to everything, you cannot block that. If you don't trust them, don't give them the keys of the kingdom...

Comment: Agreed – to be clear, the Domain Admin issue was raised by management above me – just wanted to get my facts right before getting back to them – thank you for the information.

Comment: As for the trouble of removing `builtin\administrator`, I'm not sure what you've read. I never had any problem. Remeber that `builtin\administrators` can *always* get access if they want, is documented on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207004.aspx